# Writing a postfix plugin for SMTP header and body manipulation

Tags: linux, postfix

Is there a way to develop plugin for postfix?
For example, I would like to have the plugin to manipulate SMTP fields and SMTP body content and relay the mail to specific destination based on content of the mail.

Or do I need to modify only postfix source code?

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, one way are extensions called [Milters](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html). Some are listed [here](http://www.postfix.org/addon.html).